# Unable to perform aggregation on 2 values using groupByKey in spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

This question is regarding groupByKey() in spark using scala.

Consider below data

```
Name,marks,value
Chris,30,1
Chris,35,1
Robert,12,1
Robert,20,1
```

Created below rdd

```
val dataRDD = sc.parallelize(List(("Chris",30,1),("Chris",35,1),("Robert",12,1),("Robert",20,1)))
```

I am trying to create a key value pair of this like

```
val kvRDD = dataRDD.map(rec=> (rec._1, (rec._2,rec._3)))
```

Now I want sum of both the values.

```
val sumRDD = kvRDD.groupByKey().map(rec => (rec._1,(rec._2._1.sum, rec._2._2.sum)))
```

However, I am facing below error.

```
<console>:28: error: value _2 is not a member of Iterable[(Int, Int)]
```

Can't we achieve the required using `groupByKey`?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `groupByKey`, I would suggest using the more efficient `reduceByKey`:

```
val dataRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("Chris",30,1), ("Chris",35,1), ("Robert",12,1), ("Robert",20,1)
))

val kvRDD = dataRDD.map(rec => (rec._1, (rec._2, rec._3)))

val sumRDD = kvRDD.reduceByKey{ (acc, t) =>
  (acc._1 + t._1, acc._2 + t._2)
}

sumRDD.collect
// res1: Array[(String, (Int, Int))] = Array((Robert,(32,2)), (Chris,(65,2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `kvRDD` is `array` of `tuple` so you can sum `array` values directly, You can do like below

```
val sumRDD=kvRDD.groupByKey.map(rec=>(rec._1,(rec._2.map(_._1).sum,rec._2.map(_._2).sum)))

//Output
scala> sumRDD.collect
res11: Array[(String, (Int, Int))] = Array((Robert,(32,2)), (Chris,(65,2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use reduceByKey in such scenario but still if you want to do it using groupByKey you can try the below approach. I am doing it python way you can try the same with scala.

```
 def summly(ilist):
        sum1=0
        sum2=0
        for i in ilist:
           sum1=sum1+i[0]
           sum2=sum2+i[1]
        return (sum1,sum2)

sumRDD = kvRDD.groupByKey().map(lambda x : (x[0],summly(list(x[1])))
```